# Fixed X-Axis Ticks when zooming

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I'm using ZedGraph, and I have a data series with dates for the x values.  I want the axis to be set up so that the unit is 1 day for every tick, with a label every 5 days.
When I zoom in, I don't want Zedgraph to alter labels, or recalculate the ticks. I want them fixed.  On zoom, it should just increase / decrease the space between the ticks, but the values / labels / number of ticks on the axis should not change.

Disabling Zoom/ Pan is not the solution here - I want to zoom in, just don't want to recalculate the ticks.

I tried the following to disable the autoscale, I must be missing something.
Thanks

```
_pane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.Date;
_pane.XAxis.Scale.FormatAuto = false;
_pane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStepAuto = false;
_pane.XAxis.Scale.MinorStepAuto = false;
_pane.XAxis.Scale.MajorUnit = DateUnit.Day;
_pane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 5;
_pane.XAxis.Scale.MinorUnit = DateUnit.Day;
_pane.XAxis.Scale.MinorStep = 1;
_pane.XAxis.Scale.Min = _dataset.DateTimes[0].ToOADate();
_pane.XAxis.Scale.Max = _dataset.DateTimes[_dataset.DateTimes.Length - 1].ToOADate();
```